# Listview data blank when running in background mode

Tags: react-native

I have seen a new bug in my app but can not get any solution.

In the app, `ListView`' data shown blank when running longtime in background mode. Though I did not use anything in `setInterval()`.

Is there any solution?

I am using: 
"react": *15.3.2*,
"react-native": *0.37.0*

Comment: May you please describe more, or attached some related codes so that we could investigate? Do you mean it work for running a short time? just having no idea

Comment: Code and App name I can't share as per rule. Nothing special, I have added A ListView within a  View component. It is render properly. But suppose I am out of my app ( not closed staying in stack, running on the background ) and after two days I reopen my app, there is no ListView data. This is the actual problem.

Comment: Maybe, just maybe, everytime you open your app it called the componentDidMount, and there maybe some data update function got called. And the update data function cannot get the data properly, hence return an empty list.

Comment: We use componentDidMount when after a component is mounted. But when the app is running in background mode it already did his componentDidMount. And the second thing is that I did not use any  data update function when running in background mode.

Comment: So, you mean your reopen app action, is like you did not kill it, just place it here? I don't have any idea about reopening app won't render again unless you killed it.

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was in family trip. Yes, I don't know why this is happening? This is really big issue in react native.